# Python make oneliner for multiline text in sqlnet.ora

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have following text:

```
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_TYPES_SERVER=(MD5,SHA1)
WALLET_LOCATION=
(SOURCE=
(METHOD=FILE)
(METHOD_DATA=
(DIRECTORY=/oracle/.wallets)
)
)
SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE=TRUE
```

and want to get that as a result:

```
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_TYPES_SERVER=(MD5,SHA1)
WALLET_LOCATION=(SOURCE=(METHOD=FILE)(METHOD_DATA=(DIRECTORY=/oracle/.wallets)))
SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE=TRUE
```

What is most effective way to do that with native Python (without additional external packages)?

There can be others multi-line parameters. And I don't know in advance how many parenthesis they can have.

Edit1. I don't need exact solution. At least just an algorithm.

Comment: If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code.

Comment: I need at least a way how to effectively solve this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('sqlnet.ora', 'r') as file:
    sqlnetora = file.read()
sqlnetora = re.sub(r' +', '', re.sub(r'\n+', '\n', sqlnetora))\
                .replace(' \n','\n')
text_list = sqlnetora.splitlines()
is_mvar = False # flag if we are working with multiline parameter
oneliner = []   # list with one-line parameters
mvar = []       # list for multiline parameter
for line in text_list:
    po = line.count('(')
    pc = line.count(')')
    # this is not multiline parameter
    if not is_mvar:
        if line[-1:] == ')' and po == pc:
            oneliner.append(line)
        elif line[-1:] != '=' and po == pc:
            oneliner.append(line)
        # we've found start of multiline parameter
        else:
            mpo = line.count('(')
            mpc = line.count(')')
            is_mvar = True
            mvar.append(line)
    # this is multiline parameter
    else:
        mpo += po
        mpc += pc
        # if this is last line for multiline parameter?
        if mpo == mpc:
            mvar.append(line)
            oneliner.append(('').join(mvar))
            mvar.clear()
            is_mvar = False
        # this is not last line of multiline parameter
        else:
            mvar.append(line)
print(*oneliner, sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do is to use the line number for start and end and then concatenate all lines between them. Btw, I saved your text in a file but you can directly feed it to the code as well.

```
file1 = open('myfile.txt', 'r') 
Lines = file1.readlines() 

count = 0
lineNumStart, lineNumEnd = 1, 7
outStringJoined = ""
for line in Lines: 
    if count>=lineNumStart and count<lineNumEnd:
        outStringJoined += line.strip()
    else:
        outStringJoined += line
    count+=1
print(outStringJoined)
```

To make it more flexible, you can use the pair such as ("(", ")"). If the first element of the pair is found then the code would continue concatenating until its matching pair is found!

Comment: The matter is I don't know in advance where  multi-line variable is located (the text above is just small piece of the file). To remove all new lines I can use regular expression. That is not what I wanted to. But anyway thanks for your time.